# SQL Find accounts with no collection activity in the last 45 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have a practice management software which stores different activity in different tables. 
LISTED BELOW.  The goal I am trying to accomplish is to find accounts which have a balance due, that are dormant, or have not had any activity within the past 30 days.  Activity types include Claim Submission, Payments, & Ledger Notes. I am achieving this with five queries and Vlookup function within exel.  However I would like to do this cleanly with one sql query.  Is it possible.  Below are the five Queries I am currently using.

```
SELECT xrxTrnLgr.PatId, xrxTrnLgr.Balance, 
FROM xrxTrnLgr
WHERE (xrxTrnLgr.Balance>$.01)
ORDER BY xrxTrnLgr.PatId
```

This query is to get patients who have a balance

```
SELECT xrxPat.PatId, xrxPat.Coverage, xrxPat.DctId, xrxPat.EntryDate
FROM  xrxPat
WHERE (xrxPat.EntryDate>{ts '2008-01-01 00:00:00'})
ORDER BY xrxPat.PatId
```

This query is to get Doctor Id

```
SELECT RecNo, xrxPatNotes.PatId, xrxPatNotes.NoteDate, xrxPatNotes.UserId
FROM xrxPatNotes INNER JOIN
(SELECT xrxPatNotes.PatId, Max (NoteDate) as LastDate
FROM xrxPatNotes
GROUP BY PatId) as B
ON xrxPatNotes.PatId = B.PatId
AND xrxPatNotes.NoteDate = B.LastDate
```

This query is to get most recent Ledger Note

```
SELECT xrxTrnicf.PatId,  xrxTrnicf.UserId  ,xrxTrnicf.PostDate
FROM   xrxTrnicf INNER JOIN
(SELECT xrxTrnicf.PatId, Max (PostDate) as LastDate
FROM  xrxTrnicf
GROUP BY PatId) as B
ON xrxTrnicf.PatId = B.PatId
AND xrxTrnicf.PostDate = B.LastDat
```

This query is to get most recent Claim Submitted

```
SELECT xrxTrnpay.PatId,  xrxTrnpay.UserId  ,xrxTrnpay.PostDate
FROM   xrxTrnpay INNER JOIN
(SELECT xrxTrnpay.PatId, Max (PostDate) as LastDate
FROM  xrxTrnpay
GROUP BY PatId) as B
ON xrxTrnpay.PatId = B.PatId
AND xrxTrnpay.PostDate = B.LastDate
```

This query is to get most recent Payment

Within exel I then VLOOKUP all values and subtract from today.  I then create a column to get the min value.

If someone could help me with at least combining the sql queries into one query I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show us your table definitions as 'CREATE TABLE' statements as well?

Comment: I apologize, I am not clear on how to do this.  As I said I am really a novice when it comes to SQL and have pieced together this solution from things I have read on this site.  If it helps, the data is coming out of a database in sql server 2008 and the table names are  1. xrxtrnpay 2. xrxtrnicf 3. xrxpat 4.xrxtrnlgr 5. xrxpatnotes.  I am not sure that this is what you are looking for, so I apologize in advance for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: Well, based on what I can see, I'd say you're stuck with the different queries as they return different no/type of columns. If you could have the same columns returned, then a UNION would serve your purpose

Comment: @AmitBhargava, a union can still be used here with a little hackery. See per answer for what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a 5-way union. It's rather verbose, but it would do the trick. Note that it still uses five selects, so it would not be any more efficient (in fact, I suspect it may be less efficient). It would just allow one query with one resultset:

```
SELECT PatId,
  'xrxTrnLgr' AS tablename,
  'Balance' AS key1, Balance AS value1,
  NULL AS key2, NULL AS value2,
  NULL AS key3, NULL AS value3
FROM xrxTrnLgr
WHERE (xrxTrnLgr.Balance>$.01)
UNION ALL
SELECT PatId,
  'xrxPat' AS tablename,
  'Coverage' AS key1, Coverage AS value1,
  'DctId' AS key2, DctId AS value2,
  'EntryDate' AS key3, EntryDate AS value3
FROM  xrxPat
WHERE (xrxPat.EntryDate>{ts '2008-01-01 00:00:00'})
UNION ALL
SELECT PatId,
  'xrxPatNotes' AS tablename,
  'RecNo' AS key1, RecNo AS value1,
  'NoteDate' AS key2, NoteDate AS value2,
  'UserId' AS key3, UserId AS value3
FROM xrxPatNotes INNER JOIN
(SELECT xrxPatNotes.PatId, Max (NoteDate) as LastDate
FROM xrxPatNotes
GROUP BY PatId) as B
ON xrxPatNotes.PatId = B.PatId
AND xrxPatNotes.NoteDate = B.LastDate
UNION ALL
SELECT PatId,
  'xrxTrnicf' AS tablename,
  'UserId' AS key1, UserId AS value1,
  'PostDate' AS key2, PostDate AS value2,
  NULL AS key3, NULL AS value3
FROM   xrxTrnicf INNER JOIN
(SELECT xrxTrnicf.PatId, Max (PostDate) as LastDate
FROM  xrxTrnicf
GROUP BY PatId) as B
ON xrxTrnicf.PatId = B.PatId
AND xrxTrnicf.PostDate = B.LastDat
UNION ALL
SELECT PatId,
  'xrxTrnpay' AS tablename,
  'UserId' AS key1, UserId AS value1,
  'PostDate' AS key2, PostDate AS value2,
  NULL AS key3, NULL AS value3
FROM   xrxTrnpay INNER JOIN
(SELECT xrxTrnpay.PatId, Max (PostDate) as LastDate
FROM  xrxTrnpay
GROUP BY PatId) as B
ON xrxTrnpay.PatId = B.PatId
AND xrxTrnpay.PostDate = B.LastDate
ORDER BY PatId
```

This will return one resultset with the columns (`tablename`, `PatId`, `key1`, `value1`, `key2`, `value2`, `key3`, `value3`). The `tablename` result will tell you how to interpret the key/value pair results.

Comment: Ben,  I tried this and I get a Incorrect syntax near keyword 'Union'  I deleted the lines that say this query is to get most recent claims, etc.  but still get this error.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @MichaelSigman, oops I also delete the lines that say "this query". After that it should work, can you post the exact error message? The context might help me find the bug.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.  I am adding the query in powerpivot so this is the only error that I get.  It does not give me more details.  Sorry.  I really appreciate the help by the way.

Comment: @Michael Sigman & Ben Lee: You can't have multiple `ORDER BY` clauses in a `UNION` query. There must be no more than one `ORDER BY` (at the end of the query), and it would apply to the entire result set.

Comment: @AndriyM, duh, missed that. Just needed another pair of eyes. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelSigman, I updated it to just include one ORDER BY. See if it works now.

Comment: There might be an issue also with double quotes. I think they should be single quotes instead, because that's what SQL Server expects as delimiters of string constants. Double quotes are for delimiting names (column names, table names etc.). Maybe I'm missing something, though. Same about `{ts '2008-01-01 00:00:00'}`, which doesn't look SQL Server-ish to me, although I can see that it came from the OP's query. (I *must* be missing something then!)

Comment: @AndriyM, changed to single quotes.

Comment: I now get the following errors.Ambiguous column name 'PatId'.
Ambiguous column name 'PatId'.
Invalid column name 'xrxPatNotes'.
Ambiguous column name 'PatId'.

Comment: @MichaelSigman, the invalid column name thing was from a typo. I fixed it. To fix the ambigious column name thing, you might have to add back in the table names in front of the columns. I don't have a copy of sql server in front of me to test, but if you understand how the above query works, you should be able to fix any minor problems like this by playing around with it.